# Tailwind CSS - Position border set distance below container

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I wish to position this border 42px below the text without affecting the `<p>` tag:

```
    return (
        <div className='hover:border-b-[4px]'>
            <p>Collections</p>
        </div>
    )
```

How can I accomplish this witout affecting (moving) the contents of the `<p>` tag using Tailwind?

Answer (score 0):

Apply `padding-bottom: 42px` to the `<div>` element to push the bottom border edge `42px` away from the bottom of the `<p>` element.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class='pb-[42px] hover:border-b-[4px]'>
  <p>Collections</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why exactly 42px but this will work in tailwind-css:

```
<div>
  <p>Collections</p>
  <div class="mt-[42px] h-4 w-4 bg-blue-500 hover:border-b-[4px]"></div>
</div>
```

All you have to do is make bot `<div>` and `<p>` in a `<div>`, also note that I have added h-4, w-4 and a background color to see the changes. in you case I guess you're using a framework like React or Vue, in this case probably change `class` into `className`.